# invalid 'times' argument when using lmer and predict

Tags: r, lme4, predict

I am working with physical activity data and follow-up pain data. I have a large dataset but for the shake of this example I have created a small one with the variables of my interest.

As my physical activity data are compositional in nature I am using compositional data analysis before using those variables as predictors in my mixed-effects model. My goal is to use the predict() function to predict some new data that I have created but I am receiving the folowing:

`Error in rep(0, nobs) : invalid 'times' argument`

I have googled it and I saw a post that was posted a few year ago but the answer did not work for mine.

Below is the dataset and my code:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("compositions")
library("robCompositions")
library("lme4")

dataset <- structure(list(work = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                              3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
           department = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
                                    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
           worker = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
           age = c(45, 43, 65, 45, 76, 34, 65, 23, 23, 45, 32, 76), 
           sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                             2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), pain = c(4, 
                                                                                        5, 3, 2, 0, 7, 8, 10, 1, 4, 5, 4), lpa_w = c(45, 65, 43, 
                                                                                                                                     76, 98, 65, 34, 56, 2, 3, 12, 34), mvpa_w = c(12, 54, 76, 
                                                                                                                                                                                   87, 45, 23, 65, 23, 54, 76, 23, 54), lpa_l = c(54, 65, 34, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  665, 76, 87, 12, 34, 54, 12, 45, 12), mvpa_l = c(12, 43, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   56, 87, 12, 54, 76, 87, 98, 34, 56, 23)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 -12L))

#create compositions of physical activity

dataset$comp_w <- acomp(cbind(lpa_w = dataset[,7], 
                          mvpa_w = dataset[,8]))

dataset$comp_l <- acomp(cbind(lpa_l = dataset[,9], 
                          mvpa_l = dataset[,10]))

#Make a grid to use for predictions for composition of lpa_w and mvpa_w
mygrid=rbind(
expand.grid(lpa_w = seq(min(2), max(98),5),
          mvpa_w = seq(min(12), max(87), 5)))

griddata <- acomp(mygrid)

#run the model
model <- lmer(pain ~ ilr(comp_w) + age + sex + ilr(comp_l) +
            (1 | work / department / worker),
          data = dataset)

(prediction = predict(model, newdata = list(comp_w = griddata,
                                        age = rep(mean(dataset$age, na.rm=TRUE),nrow(griddata)), 
                                        sex = rep("1", nrow(griddata)),
                                        comp_l = do.call("rbind", replicate(n=nrow(griddata), mean(acomp(dataset[,12])), simplify = FALSE)),
                                        work = rep(dataset$work, nrow(griddata)),
                                        department = rep(dataset$department, nrow(griddata)),
                                        worker = rep(dataset$worker, nrow(griddata)))))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share all your data? Now your code is not reproducible.

Comment: Specifically: is the structure you present supposed to be assigned to  a variable? WHere do `lpa_w`, `mvpa_w`, `lpa_l`, `mvpa_l` come from/how are they defined?

Comment: Hey, apologies. Now the code is corrected. lpa_w, mvpa_w, lpa_l and mvpa_l become two compositions for leisure and work hence w = work and l = leisure. lpa = light physical activity and mvpa = moderate-to-vigorous physical activity.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've actually created `comp_w` or `comp_l`. I get two columns returned by `acomp()`, which can't get thrown into a single column, so I ended up with an empty column named `comp_w` and no `comp_l`. Are you getting something different? Did you inspect what you expected?

Comment: Hi Kat, yes I get 4 extra columns in my dataset which are called comp_w[,1], comp_w[,2], comp_l[,1] and comp_l[,2]. If you type colnames(dataset) you will only get comp_w and comp_l.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assigning the results of `acomp` to an element of a data frame gives a weird data structure that messes things up downstream.

Constructing this data set (without messing up the original `dataset`):

```r
dataset_weird <- dataset
dataset_weird$comp_w <- acomp(cbind(lpa_w = dataset[,7], 
                          mvpa_w = dataset[,8]))
dataset_weird$comp_l <- acomp(cbind(lpa_l = dataset[,9], 
                                    mvpa_l = dataset[,10]))
```

The result is **so** weird that `str(dataset_weird)`, the usual way of investigating the structure of an R object, fails with

> $ comp_w    :Error in unclass(x)[i, , drop = drop] :
> (subscript) logical subscript too long

If we run `sapply(dataset_weird, class)` we see that these elements have class `acomp`. (They also appear to have an odd `print()` method: when we `print(dataset_weird$comp_w)` the results are a matrix of strings, but if we `unclass(dataset_weird$comp_w)` we can see that the underlying object is numeric [!])

This whole problem is kind of tricky since you're working with n-column matrices that are getting converted to special `acomp()` objects that are then getting converted to (n-1)-dimensional matrices (isometric log-ratio-transformed compositional data), the columns of which are then getting used as predictors.  The basic point is that `lme4`'s machinery will get confused if you have elements in your data frame that are not simple one-dimensional vectors. So you have to do the work of creating data frame columns yourself.

Here's what I came up with, with one missing piece (described below):

```r
## utility function: *either* uses a matrix argument (`comp_data`)
## *or* extracts relevant columns from a data frame (`data`):
## returns ilr-transformed values as a matrix, with appropriate column names
ilr_dat <- function(data, suffix = NULL, comp_data = NULL) {
    if (!is.null(suffix) && is.null(comp_data)) {
        comp_data <- as.matrix(data[grep(paste0(suffix,"$"), names(data))])
    }
    ilrmat <- ilr(acomp(comp_data))
    colnames(ilrmat) <- paste0("ilr", suffix, ".", 1:ncol(ilrmat))
    return(ilrmat)
}

## augment original data set (without weird compositional elements)
## using data.frame() rather than $<- or rbind() collapses matrix arguments
## to data frame rows in a way that R expects
dataset2 <- data.frame(dataset, ilr_dat(dataset, "_l"))
dataset2 <- data.frame(dataset2, ilr_dat(dataset, "_w"))

mygrid <- rbind(
    expand.grid(lpa_w = seq(min(2), max(98),5),
                mvpa_w = seq(min(12), max(87), 5)))

## generate ilr data for prediction
griddata <- as.data.frame(ilr_dat(comp_data=mygrid, suffix="_w"))

#run the model: ilr(comp_l) **not** included, see below
model <- lmer(pain ~ ilr_w.1 + age + sex  + ## ilr(comp_l) +
                  (1 | work / department / worker),
          data = dataset2)

## utility function for replication
xfun <- function(s) rep(dataset[[s]], nrow(griddata))
predict(model, newdata = data.frame(griddata,
                                    age = mean(dataset$age, na.rm=TRUE),
                                    sex = "1",
                                    work = xfun("work"),
                                    department = xfun("department"),
                                    worker = xfun("worker")))
```

This seems to work.

The reason I did not include the `_l` composition/irl in the model or the predictions is that I couldn't understand what this statement was doing:

```r
comp_l = do.call("rbind", replicate(n=nrow(griddata), mean(acomp(dataset[,12])), simplify = FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, that's exactly what I did as well and it worked. Thank you very much for all the help and the explanation. Much appreciated! That statement was calculating the mean composition of all 5 activities during leisure time.

Comment: if the answer solved your problem, you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...